# Input from user display on 2nd page

Tags: tkinter, button, label, tkinter-entry

I am trying to get input from the user and display it on the second page. It should say Hello and then the input from the entry box on the first page. I have commented out the code that isn't working. Everything else works so a copy paste will put a working snippet into python.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import Button
    
    window = Tk()
    window.title('In the Beginning')
    window.geometry("400x400")
    
    def Setting():
        name2.configure(text = 
        entry.get())
    
    name2 = Label(text = ' ')
    
    def window_2():
        window.destroy()
        window2 = Tk()
        nameLb = Label(text = 'Hello')
        nameLb.pack()
        """
        ender = Button(text = 'Quit!', command = window2.destroy())
        ender.pack()
        name2.pack()
        """
        window2.mainloop()

    greeting = Label(text = 'Name Your character:', fg = 'red', bg = 'white')
    greeting.pack()
    entry = Entry(fg = 'yellow', bg = 'blue', width = 50)
    entry.pack()
    setname = Button(text = 'set', command = Setting)
    setname.pack()
    kill = Button(text = 'Click here', command = window_2)
    kill.pack()
    name2.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

I have the name being displayed on the first page after the set button is pressed. But for some reason when I go to the second page with the other button all I see is Hello. If I have the ender button on the second page then the Label for Hello vanishes. And for some reason command = window2.destroy(), the button isn't reacting.

Comment: If I enter "Robert Holmes", it should be 'Hello Robert Holmes", rite?

Comment: Change this `window2 = Tk()` to `window2 = Toplevel()` and this too `nameLb = Label(window2,..)`

Comment: Change this to `window.withdraw()` instead `window.destroy()`

Comment: You need to write another function for quit.

Comment: Yes if Robert Holmes is typed it should say Hello Robert Holmes. If John Jacob Jinglehimer Smitt is typed it should say Hello John Jacob Jinglehimer Smitt.  Making quit another function makes sense. I will do that.

Comment: Add this ent = `StringVar()` and `entry = Entry(window, textvariable=ent...)`

Comment: So I tried to use window2 = Toplevel(), that made it so that window2 couldn't even be seen, so I kept it as window2 = Tk(). I did replace the destroy method with withdraw, that works way better. But for the grit I got rid of name2.pack() within window 2 and change nameLb to nameLb = Label(window2, text = 'Hello ' + str(entry.get())) this got the job done. I thank you for all the help you have given this allows me to progress so very much. Again thank you.

Comment: See my answer to update...HAPPY NEW YEARS!

Answer (score 1):

> But for some reason when I go to the second page with the other button all I see is Hello.

It is because you do not update the label `nameLb` in the second window.

> If I have the ender button on the second page then the Label for Hello vanishes. And for some reason command = window2.destroy(), the button isn't reacting.

It is because `command = window2.destroy()` will execute `window2.destroy()` immediately and so the *original* second window is destroyed before creating the `ender` button.  Since there is no window when the `ender` button is being created, another root window will be created explicitly and the `ender` button will be the only widget in that window and its `command` option is assigned the result of `window2.destry()` which is `None`.  That is why the `ender` button does nothing when it is clicked.

Note that it is better to specify the `master` of widgets when creating them.

Below is the modified code to fix the above issues:

```py
# avoid using wildcard import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('In the Beginning')
window.geometry("400x400")

def Setting():
    name2.configure(text=entry.get())

def window_2():
    # get what is input before destroying the first window
    who = entry.get()
    window.destroy()

    # create second window
    window2 = tk.Tk()
    window2.title("Window 2")
    window2.geometry("400x200")

    # better specify the master of widgets
    # and set the text of the label to what you want
    nameLb = tk.Label(window2, text=f'Hello {who}')
    nameLb.pack()

    # use command=window2.destroy instead
    ender = ttk.Button(window2, text='Quit!', command=window2.destroy)
    ender.pack()

greeting = tk.Label(window, text='Name Your character:', fg='red', bg='white')
greeting.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(window, fg='yellow', bg='blue', width=50)
entry.pack()

setname = ttk.Button(window, text='set', command=Setting)
setname.pack()

kill = ttk.Button(window, text='Click here', command=window_2)
kill.pack()

name2 = tk.Label(window)
name2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Misspelled the result of window2.destry() should be the result of window2.destroy()

Answer (score -1):

> Input from user display on 2nd page

- Add StringVar()
- Pass variable to `entry = Entry(window, textvariable=ent,...)`
- Create function for destroy_second_window()
- Comment in for `ender` button.

Snippet(modified):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Button

window = Tk()
window.title('In the Beginning')
window.geometry("400x400")

def Setting():
    name2.configure(text = 
    entry.get())

name2 = Label(window) 

def window_2():
    window.withdraw()
    window2 = Toplevel()
    window2.title('Toplevel')
    nameLb = Label(window2, text = f'Hello {ent.get()}')
    nameLb.pack()

    def destroy_second_window():
        window2.destroy() 

    ender = Button(window2, text = 'Quit!', command=destroy_second_window)
    ender.pack()

    
ent = StringVar()     

greeting = Label(window,text = 'Name Your character:', fg = 'red', bg = 'white')
greeting.pack()
entry = Entry(window, textvariable=ent,fg = 'yellow', bg = 'blue', width = 50)
entry.pack()
setname = Button(window,text = 'set', command = Setting)
setname.pack()
kill = Button(window,text = 'Click here', command = window_2)
kill.pack()
name2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the point of adding the `StringVar` if you can use `entry.get()`? Also the second window being a `tk.Tk` window should never be problem if the first one is destroyed.l before the second one is created.